# No buffer space available when using Dummynet in FreeBSD 9.3

Tags: freebsd, ping, ipfw

As soon as the `Dummynet` Kernel module is loaded and the appropriate `ipfw add pipe 1 from localhost to localhost` command is issued, I can no longer ping localhost — I receive the `ping: sendto: No buffer space available` error.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem myself - it appears that by bug or by feature the pipe starts working correctly as soon as some parameters of the pipe are configured. In my case, I issued the following command: `ipfw pipe 1 config delay 0ms`.